# How to perform reduceLeft on List of Futures in scala?

Tags: scala

```
val xyz =List(Future(1),Future(2),Future(3),Future(4),Future(5))
xyz.reduceLeft((a,b) => Await.result(a, 1 second) + Await.result(b, 1 second) )
```

The error which I am getting is

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
xyz.reduceLeft((a,b) => Await.result(a, 1 second) + Await.result(b, 1 second) )
```

how to solve this?

Comment: `reduce` _& friends_ can not change the **type** of the input. If you have a `List[A]` you must return an **A** _(in this case **Future[Int]**)_. A couple of alternatives, use `foldLeft` instead that allows you to change the return type _(it is even more safe, since it can work for empty collections)_. Instead of **Awaiting** for the futures _(which is a bad practice)_ return a new future using `f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y))` or use `Future.sequence` to transform a **List[Future[A]]** into a **Future[List[A]]** and then map this future to call `reduceLeft` on the inner list of ints.

Comment: is there a difference in performance (time and space complexity) between reduceLeft and Foldleft?

Comment: I would expect that `reduceLeft` is implemented in terms of `foldLeft` probably like this: `def reduceLeft(f: (A, A) => A): A = this.tail.foldLeft(this.head)(f)` - but if not, if it has its own implementation, it still should have the same performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer function for `reduceLeft` has to return the same type as the two arguments have (which is the same type as the list elements).

So you need to take two `Future[Int]` and return a `Future[Int]`.

For example

```
xyz.reduceLeft( (a,b) => a.flatMap(xa => b.map(xb => xa + xb)) )
```

The end result will be a single `Future[Int]`, so you could `Await.result` at the very end.

```
val sum = Await.result(xyz.reduceLeft(....
```

You could also use the standard library functions `Future.sequence` and `Seq.sum` here:

```
val sum = Await.result(Future.sequence(xyz).map(_.sum), 1 second)
```

Comment: future.sequence internally uses foldLeft right? so in this case I will be indirectly using foldLeft as well as map right?